# Modify Year field of Timestamp

Tags: sql, db2

I want to modify the year to 2013 and I dont want to modify the rest: months, days, etc

I want to do this for every row in the table

I know that i can add 'x' years using:

```
 Set date = date+ x YEAR  in the update statement
```

But i dont know how to achieve the constant  value of 2013 regardless of original year value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't explicitly said what you want to happen with leap-years, which could be important (which direction would they move?).  However, the basic form is pretty simple:

```
UPDATE <table> SET <column> = <column> + (2013 - YEAR(<column)) YEARS
```

Example (all statements run and verified on my local iSeries):

```
CREATE TABLE QTEMP/Example (initial TIMESTAMP NOT NULL WITH DEFAULT, 
                            updated TIMESTAMP NOT NULL WITH DEFAULT)

INSERT INTO Example VALUES(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP),
                          (TIMESTAMP(DATE('2012-02-29'), CURRENT_TIME),
                           TIMESTAMP(DATE('2012-02-29'), CURRENT_TIME)),
                          (TIMESTAMP(DATE('2012-02-28'), CURRENT_TIME),
                           TIMESTAMP(DATE('2012-02-28'), CURRENT_TIME)),
                          (TIMESTAMP(DATE('2012-03-31'), CURRENT_TIME),
                           TIMESTAMP(DATE('2012-02-31'), CURRENT_TIME)),
                          (TIMESTAMP(DATE('2013-05-08'), CURRENT_TIME),
                           TIMESTAMP(DATE('2013-05-08'), CURRENT_TIME)),
                          (TIMESTAMP(DATE('2014-09-20'), CURRENT_TIME),
                           TIMESTAMP(DATE('2014-09-20'), CURRENT_TIME)),
```

Resulting initial data:

```
initial                     updated
2012-11-14-15.05.58.246187  2012-11-14-15.05.58.246187
2012-02-29-15.05.58.000000  2012-02-29-15.05.58.000000
2012-02-28-15.05.58.000000  2012-02-28-15.05.58.000000
2012-03-01-15.05.58.000000  2012-03-01-15.05.58.000000
2013-05-08-15.05.58.000000  2013-05-08-15.05.58.000000
2014-09-20-15.05.58.000000  2014-09-20-15.05.58.000000
```

Actual statement

```
UPDATE Example SET updated = updated + (2013 - YEAR(updated)) YEARS
WHERE YEAR(updated) <> 2013
```

Resulting in:

```
initial                     updated
2012-11-14-15.05.58.246187  2013-11-14-15.05.58.246187
2012-02-29-15.05.58.000000  2013-02-28-15.05.58.000000
2012-02-28-15.05.58.000000  2013-02-28-15.05.58.000000
2012-03-01-15.05.58.000000  2013-03-01-15.05.58.000000
2013-05-08-15.05.58.000000  2013-05-08-15.05.58.000000
2014-09-20-15.05.58.000000  2013-09-20-15.05.58.000000
```

Answer (score -1):

select to_date('2014/'|| to_char(sysdate, 'mm/dd HH24:MI:SS'), 'yyyy/mm/dd HH24:MI:SS') from dual;

Comment: -1 - Several reasons - 1) You're converting it to character, when better ways exist.  2) You explicitly reference `dual` which is included only for Oracle compatibility (and isn't on every version) - there's a DB2-specific equivalent (and `dual` on DB2 has some gotchas, relating to if it's a table they created).  3) What happens if the date is '2012-02-29'?  4)  You're forgetting microseconds.  5) The OP is specifically looking for an `UPDATE` statement, and you've only provided a (unformatted) `SELECT`.

Comment: The answer is only meant as a hint. The idea is that you convert to it to a date pattern where in you do not have year, and convert it back to date with your date.

Comment: Okay, that potentially deals with _one_ of the issues I raised.  Except, you've presented it as if it would **completely** solve his problem, not as a hint...  Oh, and `SYSDATE`, `TO_CHAR()`, and `TO_DATE()` don't exist on all DB2 platforms (which he didn't specify, so you get a pass for).